Error: wrong version number when using Nodemailer with mail.com SMTP server
I'm trying to set up Nodemailer to send emails through the mail.com SMTP server, but I'm encountering the following error:
Error: AC650000:error:0A00010B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number:c:\ws\deps\openssl\openssl\ssl\record\ssl3_record.c:355:
{
 library: 'SSL routines',
 reason: 'wrong version number',
 code: 'ESOCKET',
 command: 'CONN'
}

Here is my current Nodemailer configuration:
import nodemailer from 'nodemailer';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';
import path from 'path';

// Load environment variables from .env file
dotenv.config({ path: path.resolve('.env') });

console.log('EMAIL_USERNAME:', process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME);
console.log('EMAIL_PASSWORD:', process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD);

// Create a Nodemailer transporter using SMTP with mail.com
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
  host: 'smtp.mail.com',
  port: 587, // Use 587 for STARTTLS
  secure: false, // Use false for STARTTLS
  auth: {
    user: process.env.EMAIL_USERNAME,
    pass: process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD,
  },
  tls: {
    rejectUnauthorized: false, // Allow self-signed certificates if necessary
  },
});

export const requestPasswordReset = async (req, res) => {
  const { email } = req.body;

  try {
    const user = await User.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Utilisateur non trouvé' });
    }

    const resetToken = crypto.randomBytes(32).toString('hex');
    const hashedToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(resetToken).digest('hex');
    user.resetPasswordToken = hashedToken;
    user.resetPasswordExpires = Date.now() + 3600000; // 1 hour

    await user.save();

    const resetUrl = `http://localhost:3000/reset/${resetToken}`;

    const mailOptions = {
      to: user.email,
      from: process.env.EMAIL_FROM,
      subject: 'Réinitialisation du mot de passe',
      text: `Vous recevez cet email parce que vous (ou quelqu'un d'autre) avez demandé la réinitialisation du mot de passe de votre compte.\n\n
             Cliquez sur le lien suivant ou copiez-le dans votre navigateur pour compléter le processus :\n\n
             ${resetUrl}\n\n
             Si vous n'avez pas demandé cette réinitialisation, veuillez ignorer cet email et votre mot de passe restera inchangé.\n`,
    };

    await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);

    res.status(200).json({ message: 'Email de réinitialisation envoyé' });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Erreur lors de la demande de réinitialisation de mot de passe :', error);
    res.status(500).json({ message: 'Erreur lors de la demande de réinitialisation de mot de passe' });
  }
};

I've verified that my environment variables are set correctly.
I've also tried setting secure: true with port 465, but I still encounter the same issue.
What I've Tried:
Verified that the email and password are correct.
Ensured the .env file is correctly loaded and variables are accessible.
Tested different combinations of secure and port.
Environment:
Node.js version: 20.15.0
Nodemailer version: 6.9.14
Operating System: Windows 11
What could be causing this error, and how can I resolve it?
Thank you for your help!

That looks like the error message you'd get if the secure option was set to true. Are you sure it is set to false?
